# Nested case in select

Tags: sql, oracle

Where is my mistake?

```
select dr.ders_code, dr.year, 
case when dr.muf_sq is not null then 
case when (select muf_sq_id from mufredat_sq m  join ders_stud_ref dr on dr.muf_sq = m.muf_sq_id) = dr.muf_sq then dr.muf_sq end
end 
from ders_stud_ref dr
```

Comment: where is your problem/ error?

Comment: @Aleksej in 2nd nested case: select case ((select muf_sq_id from mufredat_sq m  join ders_stud_ref dr on dr.muf_sq = m.muf_sq_id) = dr.muf_sq) then dr.muf_sq end. I cant run it

Comment: Are you having an error? if so, what error? or are you having an unexpected result? and, if so, what did you expect?. Also, please edit the question instead of adding comments to clarify

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake is

```
select muf_sq_id 
                from mufredat_sq m  
                join ders_stud_ref dr on dr.muf_sq = m.muf_sq_id
```

may return more then one row

I think you need something like

```
select dr.ders_code, dr.year, 
case when dr.muf_sq is not null then 
case when exists (select muf_sq_id 
            from mufredat_sq m  
           where dr.muf_sq = m.muf_sq_id) then dr.muf_sq end
end 
from ders_stud_ref dr
```